# mysql check if user has more then x transactions or a rating over x from a different table and use a where OR

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select if a user rating (user.rating) is greater then 6 or if the user has more then 100 transactions (transaction table count). Basically count how many transactions the user has then where (transaction count >= 100 OR user rating >= 6).

Try #1:

```
$user_ach_list = $db->execute("SELECT user.*, "
 . "(SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM transaction WHERE transaction.user_id=user.id AND transaction.type='L' AND transaction.status='S') AS record_count "
 . "FROM user WHERE (user.rating >= '6' OR trans >= '100') AND user.country = 'US' AND (user.can_borrow = '1' OR user.can_lend = '1')");
```

Try #2

```
$user_ach_list = $db->execute("SELECT user.*, COUNT(transaction.id) as record_count FROM `user`, `transaction` WHERE transaction.user_id=user.id AND transaction.type='L' AND transaction.status='S' AND (user.rating >= '6' OR record_count >= '100') AND user.country = 'US' AND (user.can_borrow = '1' OR user.can_lend = '1')");
```

Comment: No I need to compare with either a count of transactions > 100 or user rating > 6. Both in separate tables.

Comment: The duplicate topic shows you how to filter on an aggregate function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `JOIN` probably after getting the `COUNT()` like

```
SELECT user.*, 
xxx.record_count 
FROM `user`
JOIN ( select user_id, count(*) as record_count from `transaction`
where transaction.type='L' AND transaction.status='S' 
group by user_id) xxx
 ON xxx.user_id = user.id 
 WHERE (user.rating >= '6' OR xxx.record_count >= '100') 
 AND user.country = 'US' 
AND 1 IN (user.can_borrow , user.can_lend);
```

Comment: What does xxx represent in this?

Comment: @MarcAlexander, it's a table alias which is needed for the subquery or inline view